# How i change order status automatically to "completed" from "delivered" after 15 days in wordpress woocommerce site

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the custom order statuses plugin for custom order status.

our shop has 15 days return policy.

so, I want to change the order status "Delivered" to "Completed" after 15 days.
it means when change status Delivered that time to 15 days later automatically changes order status to "Completed"

I tried the code below but not working for me.

```
function setCompletedAfter15Days(){
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'status' => 'delivered',
            'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - 15 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ),

    ) );

    foreach ($orders as $order){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }} wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'setCompletedAfter15Days' );
```

Comment: You'll need a cronjob which periodically checks the expiry.

Comment: already i'm using cronjob for logistics. not sure how I called here